# insert dynamic columns in mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mybatis

How to get the value of a dynamic column in mybatis ?

```xml
<insert id="insertWording" parameterType="my.pkg.Wording">
INSERT INTO wordings
(id, parentId, <foreach collection="@my.pkg.LangUtls@getLangs()" item="item" separator=",">${item}<foreach>)
VALUE
(#{id}, #{parentId}, <foreach collection="@my.pkg.LangUtls@getLangs()" item="item" separator=","> ??? <foreach> })
</insert>
```

`LangUtils.getLangs()` returns something like the follwing

```js
["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"];
```

then what is the ??? should be ? I want to access value like `theWordingInstance[oneOfTheLangsProp]`.

since the prop1...propN is very much alike, i don't want to repeat a long list.

Answer (score 0):

finally got it working, it should be something like `#{${item}}`